# Global LabelStyle option does not work with SetOptions

Tags: plotting, options, style

I want to set global options for a plot, so I used the `SetOptions` command.
However, some of the options don't seem to be applied. More specifically, this is the case for the `LabelStyle` option. My plots still appear with a quite tiny frame label despite setting it to 20 pt. The weird thing is that it works for the other options, just not for `LabelStyle`. When adding a label style option to each plot seperately, it does work.

My code reads

```
SetOptions[
{Plot, ListPlot, ListLogPlot, ListLinePlot}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> 20, FrameTicksStyle -> 16
]
```

There are probably a ton of workarounds but I'd really like to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me with Version 12.3.  What version are you using?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Problem exists in 12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)

Comment: I got the same problem. From what I understood, the option PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
override the others.